# Calculating varied summation formula?

Tags: math, sum, formula

I'm trying to pragmatically emulate my calculator's summation function without the use of loops, the reason why is that they become very expensive once the function gets bloated. So far, I know of the formula n(n+1)/2, but that only works if the function looks like:

from X = 1 to 100, Σ (X), result = 5050.

Without a loop, is there a way to implement a function where:

from X = 1 to 100, Σ (X^2+X)?

EDIT: Note that the formula must account for all possible function bodies.

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula Σ (X^2+X) is equal to Σ (X) + Σ (X^2). You already know how to calculate Σ (X).

As for the Σ (X^2), this is known as *Square Pyramidal Number*. You can see a longer explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number), but the formula is:

> n<sup>3</sup>/3 + n<sup>2</sup>/2 + n/6

Together, that's

> n<sup>3</sup>/3 + n<sup>2</sup>/2 + n/6 + n(n+1)/2

Or

> (n<sup>3</sup>+2n)/3 + n<sup>2</sup>

Comment: I know this. But, is there a way to implement this in a formula without knowing the function body? Or am I inevitably forced to do checks to see what formula to use? Using the slower loop method accounts for every possible function body, and I am asking if there is a faster alternative.

Comment: @JohanZ. A. I don't understand how your comment, or what it has to do with your question / my answer.

Comment: Is there not a singular formula that would account for all function bodies? ..I don't know how to make it clearer than this!

Comment: "*how to make it clearer than this*" - "Is there a way to reduce any iterative summation function to a non-iterative analytic function". And *my* answer is, don't know, but don't think so.

Comment: I guess then I'll have to continue using a loop, but thanks for your assistance.